# how to add a class attribute in a ul tag

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
var ul=document.createElement("UL");
ul.Class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked";                   

var li=document.createElement("LI");
var x=document.createElement("a");
var linkText=document.createTextNode("text for link");

x.appendChild(linkText);
x.title="title of link";
x.href="link address";

li.appendChild(x);
ul.appendChild(lidom);
insertHere.appendChild(ul);
```

when I execute the above code the style in "nav nav-pills nav-stacked" is not applied

Comment: *"how to add a class attribute in a ul tag"* Not to nitpick, but because it's an important distinction: That's not a "`ul` tag". It's a `ul` **element**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class` should be `className`:

```
ul.className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked";
```

...because JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `Class` and `class` aren't the same thing, and because when the DOM bindings for JavaScript were being created, they couldn't use `class` because at that time, in JavaScript, you couldn't write `ul.class = ...` because `class` was a reserved word and you couldn't use it in a property literal like that. (You can now, as of ES5 in 2009, but of course that was more than a decade after the bindings were created.)

The other reflected attribute with an unusual name is `htmlFor`, which is for the `for` attribute (for instance, on `label` elements).